# How to keep the chrome instance started by selenium open after an error is encountered or the program ends

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying out Selenium chromedriver for a few days and it has been working perfectly fine but yesterday it started behaving a little abnormally and closed the chrome instance whenever an error was encountered or the program was finished (This wasn't happening earlier) and I want to keep the Chrome instance running so that I can resolve the errors.
I tried quite a few methods like adding the detach experimental option and also making the driver global all of which didn't seem to work
I'm using Visual Studio Code as my editor and Python version 3.9.0 and Selenium version 3.141.0

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service

chrome_options = Options() 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
global driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Here is an example of the code I wanna write and the options I tried to keep the window running. If you know of a way other than these then please tell. It would help a lot

Comment: Did you always use the `webdriver_manager` library?  Is it possible `ChromeDriverManger` is causing the driver to close after the script ends?

Comment: Yeah I was using that from the start